# How to pass regular expression to the command find in Linux?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, ubuntu

When I type command

`find ./ -iname "*.pdf"` or `find ./ -iname \*.pdf`

all pdf files under current folder tree are listed. 
Similarly,

`find ./ -iname "*.doc"`

lists all the doc files.

My question is how to list both types of files? I tried commad like

`find ./ -iname "*.{pdf,doc}"`

But that does not work.

Comment: You're mistaking brace expansion for a type of glob pattern. It's a completely different type of expansion, specific to `bash` and some other shells, that isn't recognized by the `-iname` primitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using glob you can use `-o` (OR)`:

```
find . \( -iname "*.pdf" -o -iname "*.doc" \)
```

Or using regex:

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*\.(pdf|doc)$'
```

On OSX `find` use:

```
find -E . -regex '.*\.(pdf|doc)$'
```